# "Get on one's nerves" VS "Get to someone"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms, expressions

Could anyone let me know how the following examples differ in meaning?

- She’s always moaning. It really [gets on my nerves](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-on-someones-nerves).
- She’s always moaning. It really [gets to me](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-to).

> - Get on someone's nerves: 
>   If someone or something gets on your nerves, they **annoy** or irritate you.

> - Get to someone: 
>   to **annoy** or upset someone.

To me, they both convey a same concept.

Comment: They are essentially the same.

Comment: Yes, the same. And both somewhat informal. Probably choose between based on your intended audience.